# Multiple Classes that extend IntentService or just one?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have several things I want to run in the background using IntentService and `scheduleJob`.

Should I have a new class that extends `IntentService` for each different function I want to do, or should I have only one class that extends `IntentService` and have some sort of identifier to split the intents to determine what function should be called?

Answer (score 0):

An `IntentService` is created to do some specific task. After completing its task the `IntentService` stopItself.

If you are trying to execute different task at same time then you have to create separate IntentServices for this or if you want all task will execute one by one then you can use same `IntentService`.

For same `IntentService` you can differentiate your task by sending data through Intent using `putExtra(key, value);`